# Traversing through CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, loops, csv, while-loop, counter

I have this code :

```
<?php
   $handle = fopen("GeneratePicklist.csv", "r");
   $data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",");
?>
```

Which opens up a php file and converts it into a php array. Then I will list out the array contents and display them into a formatted page. I have this code and it's working.

```
<?php
    echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
        <tr>
            <td class=\"dataHeader\" width=\"100\">Mat.Loc.</td>
            <td class=\"dataHeader\" width=\"20\">Qty</td>
            <td class=\"dataHeader\">Description</td>
            <td class=\"dataHeader\" width=\"150\">Part Number</td>
            <td class=\"dataHeader\" width=\"30\">Multiplier</td>
            <td class=\"dataHeader\" width=\"80\">Total Qty</td>
        </tr>
";
$locatePartNoString = array_search("Part Number",$data);
$arrayStart = $locatePartNoString-1;
end($data);
$lastField = key($data);
$counter = ($lastField - $arrayStart);
$arrayBegin = $locatePartNoString+6;
while($counter>0) {
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td class=\"centered\"><span class=\"title\">*".$data[$arrayBegin+4]."*</span><br>".$data[$arrayBegin+4]."</td>
            <td id=\"qty".$counter."\" class=\"centered\">".$data[$arrayBegin+1]."</td>
            <td>".$data[$arrayBegin+2]."</td>
            <td class=\"centered\">".$data[$arrayBegin]."</td>
            <td class=\"centered\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"multiplier".$counter."\" name=\"multiplier".$counter."\" value=\"1\" size=\"3\" style=\"border:1px dotted #CCC;\"></td>
            <td class=\"centered\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"total".$counter."\" name=\"total".$counter."\" value=\"1\" size=\"3\" style=\"border:1px dotted #CCC;\"></td>
        </tr>

    ";
    $counter--;
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

What I am trying to do is the traverse through the CSV file and select certain data only within the coverage of `$arrayBegin` variable and the last part of my CSV data. I have done the first line and its working good but I do not know how to increment so my pointer moves to the next line of the CSV file and do the same formula as my first line of data.

Here's a sample of the CSV content, 7 fields:

```
ÊÊ,Part Number,Qty,Description,BB Type,Material Location,Serial Number
ÊÊ,013224-001,1,"PCA,DDR2-800,MINIDIMM MOD256MBx 40",BOM,ASSY,ID121608ZS
ÊÊ,122657-00A,1,SOFTWARE TEST (US M3 CTO),BOM,ASSY,
ÊÊ,376383-002,8,"ASSY, BLANK,SFF",BOM,ASSY,
ÊÊ,458943-003,1,"CA ASSY, SFP BATTERY, 15 POS, 28AWG, 24",BOM,ASSY,
ÊÊ,460499-001,1,"ASSY, 4/V650HT BATTERY CHARGER MODULE",BOM,ASSY,
ÊÊ,499256-001,2,"ASSY, BLANK,MEDIA BAY,ML350G6",BOM,ASSY,
ÊÊ,500203-061,2,"DIMM,4GB PC3-10600R,256Mx4,RoHS",BOM,ASSY,RAKWF8DXV2Q100
```

I just need to select certain data from each line and then move on to the next line. How do i traverse to the next line using my while loop? Thank you for your future responses.

Comment: Use a for loop or a foreach loop instead of a while loop.

Comment: or move your search inside the while loop

Comment: @arxanas, thanks for the comment, but I don't really know how to do it yet. I'm just starting PHP.

Comment: @Oliver which part do you mean, is it `array_search` part?

Comment: No the search where you select your needed data.

Comment: Take a look at PHP's [for loops](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), and then at the [example provided at fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: @Oliver Which one do you mean? I am actually just searching the "Part Number" string just to mark the start of the the coverage.

Comment: This part: "I just need to select certain data from each line and then move on to the next line." You can do this inside the while loop.

Comment: @Oliver, it is what I am doing, that's why I am adding values to my `$data[]` array. I cannot however make it move to the next line, I do not really know how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe I should go to bed. :-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is typically how you go through a CSV file, starting with what you have already:

```
$handle = fopen("GeneratePicklist.csv", "r");
$firstRow = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",");
$partNumberPosition = array_search("Part Number", $firstRow, true);
```

At this point you have read the first line, which normally contains the field names. You have also determined at which column the 'Part Number' is at.

And to fetch the rest:

```
// the function `fgetcsv()` will return `false` when the end-of-file is reached
while (false !== ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 5000))) {
    // we have read a(nother) row of data
    // if you're not interested in the columns before the 'Part Number'
    // you can slice them off
    $row = array_slice($row, $partNumberPosition);
    // at this point, $row contains:
    // 0 => the part number
    // 1 => the quantity
    // etc...
}
// we're done, close the file
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Thank you Jack! However, this will work if I start traversing from the start of my CSV file, which is not the case, because the CSV file is actually a collection of different data, of which I am only trying to traverse from where it finds the value `Part Number` then start from there. Is it also possible to use your code to do this?

Comment: @JudeJitsu You mean you're only interested in the columns starting from `Part Number` onwards? I've edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

After you parse or during the parse of the while loop you can test for conditions.  (This is a class method I wrote so ignore the class stuff :))

```
private function logicMakeCSVTable(){

    $this->importData = Array();
        $i = 0;
        while($row = fgetcsv($this->handle, 999999, ",")){

            $num = count($row);
            for($c=0; $c < $num; $c++){

                $this->importData[$i][$c] = $row[$c];
            }   

            $i++;
        }

        $_SESSION['ImportData']  = "";
        $_SESSION['ImportData'] = $this->importData;

}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. Let me study this first, because this is very advanced for me already :D haha.. How exactly can I apply this to my code?

Comment: your CSV file is looped in the while($row=fgetcsv($handle, 999999, ","))  The first thing you do is ask for the row count of the array.  Then in the for statement loop through each of the rows with the For statement.  What you end up with is a two dimensional array with $importData[ROW][COLUMN]  Then you can just call (Row 1 Column 5)  as $importData[1][5]

Comment: Thank you Alex! Will digest this :)